# iOS7 Map Kit remove default location icons

Tags: ios, ios7, mapkit

I am wondering if it's possible to **remove all the default icons from the map kit**. I did a lot of researches and tried a couple of different ways. Couldn't find any way to do this. Don't know if anybody can help us out.

[image: Map]

Comment: did you try browsing the map view's view hierarchy at runtime? You might be able to find the views and set them to hidden--but I think that might be too hack-y for production.

Comment: nielsbot, thank you for your idea, i tried that way, but i thought those icons are annotations. so i was debugging that way. but looks like it's nothing related to annotation. so i kind of get lost at that time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It won't get rid of all those icons (I think the road markings will stay) but you can use the iOS 7 `MKMapView` property `showsPointsOfInterest`, setting it to `NO` to remove shops and other icons.

```
[myMapView setShowsPointsOfInterest:NO]
```

From the docs:

> When this property is set to YES, the map displays icons and labels for restaurants, schools, and other relevant points of interest. The default value of this property is YES.

Comment: But its removing only few icons not all i want plain mapview without any labels and icons in Map view how to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

From what I know Apple is not possible to delete the icons kit IOs7 the maps, there may be some way to let him invisible, but could not find a way to do the same as you said you tried several ways I tried too and got no success, I have helped

Comment: Thanks for trying out for me Femando. Hope there is a way to hide them like you said.