# How to show ios map without labels?

Tags: ios, dictionary, mapkit

Is there any way to show only the pure map in ios? Without any text, label or annotation.

[Sample iOS Map](https://www.apple.com/tr/ios/maps/images/redesigned_hero_2x.png)

For ex, in that picture there is a lot of texts, labels..

Comment: Yups, You can use mapView. Use `MKMapTypeStandard`

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS7 Map Kit remove default location icons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19600275/ios7-map-kit-remove-default-location-icons)

Answer (score 0):

Somehow... From iOS7 you can provide your own tiles, but you lose map kit original tiles.
Mattt has written an interesting post on [NSHipster, you should check it](http://nshipster.com/mktileoverlay-mkmapsnapshotter-mkdirections/)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to try the [Mapbox tools](http://mapbox.com/mobile) to allow full map customization.